# undefined reference to static method error

Tags: c++, static, function-calls

I am having an issue with my function call

```
static classname *makeclass ( char ch, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){

    cin >> ch >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
    Ship **ptr = 0;
    if ( ch != 'A' || ch != 'B' || ch != 'C' || ch  != 'D'){
            throw invalid_argument ("Error : invalid character input ");
    }

    else if ( ch == 'A'){
            classname **ptr = new derivedclassname*[5];
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
                    ptr[i] = new derivedclass (x1,y1,x2,y2);
            }
            return *ptr;
    }

    return *ptr;

}
```

In my main file :

```
main () {
 classname *p = classname::*makeclass ( x1,y1,x2,y2);

}
```

My error:

```
Ship.cpp:81:14: warning: ‘classname* makeclass(char, int, int, int, int)’ defined but not      used [-Wunused-function]
static classname *makeclass ( char ch, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
          ^
/tmp/cc1eUoXA.o: In function `main':
testclass.cpp:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `classname::makeclass(char, int, int, int, int)'
```

Comment: Notwithstanding the various issues with the syntax, why are you passing parameters to the `makeclass` function since they are passed by value and filled by the `cin` call within ?

Comment: `static` looks wrong, unless you have this inline in a class declaration! Otherwise the linker sees this only private for the compilation unit it was defined in.

Answer (score 0):

This code has a **lot** of issues.

```
static classname *makeclass ( char ch, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
```

This function should not be static, since, according to the information you provided, it is not located in the same file as the `main` function.

Also, you don't even need to pass these parameters to begin with, because of the next line:

```
    cin >> ch >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2;
```

Everyone of these should be declared locally in the function.

```
    Ship **ptr = 0;
```

This pointer to pointer variable seems to be shadowed by a variable of the same name declared later... This should be avoided at all costs.

```
    if ( ch != 'A' || ch != 'B' || ch != 'C' || ch  != 'D'){
            throw invalid_argument ("Error : invalid character input ");
    }
```

So, `ch` is valid if it has **at the same time** the values `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, and `'D'`. As it is, your function will always throw an exception...

```
    else if ( ch == 'A'){
            classname **ptr = new derivedclassname*[5];
```

This declaration shadows a previously declared variable.

```
            for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
                    ptr[i] = new derivedclass (x1,y1,x2,y2);
            }
            return *ptr;
```

Let's suppose you meant `derivedclassname` instead of `derivedclass`.
Here you return a dereferenced pointer to the first pointer, meaning you only correctly return the address of the first `classname` you have created.
The four following ones are lost, and you have created a memory leak.

```
    }

    return *ptr;
```

Ah, the best part comes last, you are dereferencing a pointer with a 0 value, which is undefined behaviour and will probably crash your program.

```
}
```

Finally, your main should look like:

```
main () {
    classname *p = makeclass ( x1,y1,x2,y2);
}
```

since you are simply calling a function. A function that does NOT belong to a class.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still working on the problem from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23601774/class-factory-returns-a-pointer-to-the-instance-of-a-new-derived-class, you need to define the function as:

```
classname* classname::makeclass ( char ch, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
// ....
}
```